# Samsung Galaxy S stuck at bootloop

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, boot, boot-loop

I've bricked my old Galaxy S (GT-I9000) into a bootloop.

Trying to fix that, I've uploaded Semaphore's ClockworkMod Recovery to my device successfully via Linux.

However, when I press VUP+POWER+HOME, I get to the boot screen and it keeps flashing without booting into recovery mode.

Download mode works fine.

What can I do to restore the functionality of my device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this worked: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=30206455.

Basically I flashed zImage from FixRecovery.tar and removed my SIM (Don't know why that works, it's probably not required).

Comment: Is that safe? Will it change your official ROM? Will it wipe any data on your phone - contacts, SMS, photos, etc.? I am new in this stuff.

Comment: @Anar don't know man. Follow at your own risk. My phone is dead now, for other reasons though. But yeah that changes the "official ROM", and always **backup** when you're messing with ROMs.

Answer (score 0):

You should try flashing a stock rom on your Galaxy S with Odin.

Comment: I don't have Windows at the moment, and apparently Odin doesn't work with Linux.

Comment: Checking the [Odin tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/odin/info) here, you can find an alternative working on Linux as well: [Heimdall](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/heimdall/info) (again a tag-wiki here ;)